# Why a value of type null cannot be used as a default parameter with type double?

Tags: c#, optional-parameters

Quick Question:

[**MSDN - Named and Optional Arguments (C# Programming Guide)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) states clearly that

> "*Optional arguments enable you to omit arguments for some parameters.
>   Both techniques can be used with methods, indexers, **constructors**,
>   and delegates."*

So instead of this:

```
class MyClass
{

//..

public MyClass() { // Empty Constructor's Task }
public MyClass(SomeType Param1) { // 2nd Constructor's Task }
public MyClass(SomeType Param1, SomeType Param2) { // 3rd Constructor's Task }
}
```

I should be able to do this:

```
class MyClass
    {
        //..

        public MyClass(SomeType Param1 = null, SomeType Param2 = null)
        {
            if (Param1)
            {
                if (Param2)
                {
                    // 3rd constructor's Task
                }
                else
                {
                    // 2nd constructor's Task
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!Param2)
                {
                    // Empty constructor's Task
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Then why this is not working:

```
public MyClass(double _x = null, double _y = null, double _z = null, Color _color = null)
{
   // ..
}
```

Telling me:

> A value of type "null" cannot be used as a default parameter because
>   there are no standard conversions to type 'double'

Comment: If there's one thing I've learned, that is that the downvoter will never see this question because he will not return to your post :D

Comment: @Vucko but then professional users like you will come and see it, will know that it is not fair because nothing is wrong and this **IS** useful, and upvote it ;)

Comment: Yeah, I thought that it's a cool question, and upvoted it :D

Comment: Thank you. Now go back to Android :P @Vucko

Comment: Haha, right on, man! I like C++, C# and C as well, don't make me go :D

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`double` is a [value type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx). You'd need to wrap it in [`Nullable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx) or `?` for shorthand, to indicate that it is nullable.

```
public MyClass(double? _x = null, double? _y = null, double? _z = null, Color _color = null)
{
   // ..
}
```

Comment: Hi David, but then it says "_I can't convert `double?` to `double`_" when trying to assign the parameter's value (double?) to the private member's (double)

Comment: `Nullable<T>` (as explained in the documentation linked in my answer) exposes `.Value` to allow you to get the underlying value type.  Keep in mind that if you are going to do this, you would also want to check `.Nullable<T>.HasValue` and handle the case where it is null appropriately.

Comment: Use `if (_x.HasValue) { do something with _x.Value}`

Comment: Looks like this is not a good idea to use it with constructors especially that I have all double parameters

Comment: Optional parameters can be very handy, but they are often a sign of bad class design when there are a large number of them.  Usually this is a Single Responsibility Principle violation.

Comment: I will drop this design. But thanks for solving the question, in seconds! @DavidL

Answer (score 3):

As David explained in his answer, Double is not a nullable type. In order to assign it a null value, you'll have to convert Double to `System.Nullable<double>` or `double?`

The full answer will look something like:

```
public void MyMethod(double? param = null) { }
```

The obvious problem here is that instead of just passing it a `double` value, you'll instead have to pass it a `double?` value instead.

I'm not sure of the exact scope of this functionality but you can always refer to defaults instead. For instance:

```
public void MyMethod(double param = double.MinValue) 
{ 
    if (param == double.MinValue) 
        return; 
}
```

Or something like that.